# Introduction to Local Storage Adapters

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage

I am quite a novice when it comes to web application development. The projects that I have done thus far have purely been Client Side and Jquery powered.

Recently I made a discovery that Javascript has an MVC framework (http://backbonejs.org/)

This really excites me as about 90% of my experience to date has been with Javascript, so the possibility of using an MVC framework within a familiar coding language is actually quite awesome.

After some more reading and probing I discovered a local storage adapter for backbone:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html

Basically if I have understood this correctly - it will store and retrieve data in cookies

So the above framework (backbone) and addin (local storage) will allow web applications to operate in a "server-less" environment.

Before I get crucified by any techies - I do understand that this is a very generous, generic and simplified statement - but I am just trying to find out a few things at this point:

1. Is my understanding of the framework correct?
2. Has anyone had any development experience with the above?
3. Where can I get novice level tutorials on developing MVC Web applications that use Backbone.js

Looking forward to the discussion and your answers

Answer (score 1):

> Is my understanding of the framework correct?

First off there are several "mvc" like frameworks for Javascript besides for Backbone.js (assuming you consider backbone.js an mvc framework, take at look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745782/is-backbone-js-really-an-mvc) as well as the [official documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-mvc)) for example [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/), [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/). That said local Storage is a feature of HTML5 and isn't specific to backbone.js (so the browser would need to support it, here's a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800238/javascript-html5-localstorage) with some more info on `localStorage`), what the backbone.js localStorage adapter does is saves the backbone.js data to localStorage instead of the server.

> Has anyone had any development experience with the above?

Yes (you can take a look at the questions tagged with backbone.js here on SO for starters...).

> Where can I get novice level tutorials on developing MVC Web
>   applications that use Backbone.js

Have a look at this [site](http://backbonetutorials.com/) for some backbone.js tutorials.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!! Really appreciate the effort and excellent answer - I see backbone is widely supported here on SO, which is very important, but what do you think of Ember? I see it is rated one of the best, and when compared to backbone, specifically with the way in which it refreshes the view, I see it is superior, what are your contentions?

Comment: I haven't actually used ember.js myself.

Comment: ok thanks man, well on a high level here is an article that weighs up the various frameworks, ember seems to come up trumps....

Comment: Thanks I actually already did see that article, it really depends on your specific needs.