# How do I create an MVC app design using backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have a todo object and a user object on the server. I would like a controller to serve both objects in one Json object. Would the backbone way be to do it in the View?

Answer (score 0):

Check that: http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/

This is a good example

Edit:

Indeed backbone is a MV* implementation, not a real MVC. You pointed it out right, the view is also the controller.

Comment: I know it says todoMVC. but Im not sure i see a controller implementation in the source code. https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/backbone

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Backbone.View is the Controller. I think this answers my question
[Is Backbone.js really an MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745782/is-backbone-js-really-an-mvc)